# value in list as linq join condition

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, join

I want to write a linq to have something like this

```
from acc in container.vwAccounts
orderby acc.Name ascending
join p in container.Projects.Where(x => !x.Deleted.HasValue || !x.Deleted.Value)
on acc.accId in p.Projects.FundingAccounts.Select(f => f.accId).toList() into j
where j.Any()
select new CountModel { AccId = acc.accId, Name = acc.NAME, Count = j.Count() };
```

basically selecting, for each account funding one or more projects, the number of projects that are being partially or totally funded by it. I just can't figure out how to get around
this part of the query

```
on acc.accId in p.Projects.FundingAccounts.Select(f => f.accId)
```

It is not accepting it.

Comment: What's the error that it spits out?

Comment: What is the compilation error?